# Docker local set up, can't access app in browser

Tags: docker

Good day. Can I ask for some help? I just started to learn docker and create my local set. All of my containers(nginx, app, mysql) are running ok but I can't access my test app in browser.

Here's my docker-compose.yml file

```js
version: '3'

services:
    nginx:
        image: nginx:stable-alpine
        container_name: nginx
        ports: 
            - "8088:80"
        volumes:
            - ./src:/var/www/html
            - ./nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
        depends_on: 
            - mysql
            - php

    mysql:
        image: mysql:5.7.22
        container_name: mysql
        tty: true
        ports: 
            - "3306:3306"
        volumes: 
            - ./mysql:/var/lib/mysql
        environment: 
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: localdb

    php:
        build: 
            context: .
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
        container_name: php
        volumes: 
            - ./src:/var/www/html
        ports: 
            - "9000:9000"
```

And here's my default.conf for nginx

```js
server {
    listen 80;
    index index.html index.html;
    servername localhost;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    root /var/www/html/public;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html?$query_string;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass php:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.html;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }
}
```

Comment: Which port are you trying to open ?

Comment: I am trying to open it in port 81 since port 80 is already allocated

Answer (score 3):

According to your comment, the problem is located at your docker-compose file. You want to access your nginx server on port 81, but you bind your nginx on port 8088.
So simply change the port binding from `8088:80` to `81:80`. This should fix your problem.

If you want to learn more about port binding, just have a look at the documentation: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#ports

Here is a fixed example:

```
 nginx:
    image: nginx:stable-alpine
    container_name: nginx
    ports: 
        - "81:80"
    volumes:
        - ./src:/var/www/html
        - ./nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    depends_on: 
        - mysql
        - php
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because containers can't access your host (That is your main os) you have to use `-p` for connecting the ports of your container to your computer (main os)

For example you use `docker run npm`
and imagine by your setup `npm` runs at port 3000

now you have to do networking of your container

use `docker run -p 3000:3000 npm`

The -p 3000:3000 says that your 3000 port of your container now attach to the 3000 port of your main os and now you can see your site (that is run on your container in your main os web browser in the specific port (3000))

Comment: also in your docker-compose.yml in services ----> nginx , you should change port to 80:80 because your default nginx port that is listening is 80

Comment: so, in your example `docker run -p 3000:3000 npm` `npm` is the container name right?

Comment: either could be the name of container of the name of image

Answer (score 1):

I am new to this and I don't really know what I did, but it worked without running `docker run -p [port:port] [container]` command. I did some changes on my docker-compose.yml and default.conf

I was so happy that it is running now, but it would be great if someone could just explain how it worked. Thanks for all the response.

docker-compose.yml

```js
version: '3'

services:
    nginx:
        image: nginx:stable-alpine
        container_name: nginx
        ports: 
            - "80:80"
        volumes:
            - ./src:/var/www/html
            - ./nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
        depends_on: 
            - mysql
            - php

    mysql:
        image: mysql:5.7.22
        container_name: mysql
        tty: true
        ports: 
            - "3306:3306"
        volumes: 
            - ./mysql:/var/lib/mysql
        environment: 
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: localdb

    php:
        build: 
            context: .
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
        container_name: php
        volumes: 
            - ./src:/var/www/html
        ports:
            - "9000:9000"
```

default.config

```js
server {
    listen 80;
    index index.html index.html;
    server_name localhost;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    root /var/www/html/public;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html?$query_string;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass php:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.html;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }
}
```